# How to compile native applications using DDK?

Tags: compilation, native, wdk

I tried to compile native applications using DDK, but I got "don't know how to make '\nt.lib'" error. How to fix this?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Why would you need the DDK to compile an application?  Please just state what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what the results were.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it and don't try it. The result will be undefined. DDK is for drivers, not for applications.

Comment: If native applications are not compiled with DDK, how native applications are compiled?

Comment: DDK stands for **Driver** Development Kit. Basic application doesn't require anything besides a compiler. More advanced stuff might require various libraries and SDKs (Software Development Kit)